# Does ES6 Tail Call Optimization Cover Generators?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, tail-recursion

Does ES6's support for tail call optimization cover tail calls in generators?

Suppose I have this generator for integers >= 0:

```
var nums = function* (n) {
    n = n || 0;
    yield n;
    yield* nums(n + 1);
};
```

Currently, in Chrome and Firefox, it adds a stack level with each recursive call and eventually runs into a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error. Will this still occur once ES6 is fully implemented?

(I know I can write the above generator iteratively and not run into the error. I'm just curious about whether TCO will take care of recursively defined generators.)

Comment: not sure about generators and TCO in ES6, but according to [this compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), TCO is not yet implemented in any browsers (as of 5-8-15) which explains (in part) why you're seeing the call stack explode..

Comment: Just saying, you could remove the first line of your function by giving `n` a default value of `0` (i.e. `function* (n = 0) {`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a function call is made, according to the section [Function call evaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-calls),

> 8. Let *tailCall* be IsInTailPosition(*thisCall*)
> 9. Return ? EvaluateCall(*func, ref, arguments, tailCall*)

The call will be evaluated based on the `IsInTailPosition`'s result. And if if we check [`IsInTailPosition`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isintailposition),

> 5. If body is the *FunctionBody* of a *GeneratorBody*, return **false**.

So, if the function body is a generator, then Tail Call Optimization will not be done.

Comment: What do you supposed the reason for this restriction is?